# simple jQuery dialog locks Chrome, IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The following HTML shows a button and invokes a jQuery dialog when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog">
    </div>
    <button>
        Open</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true
            });

            $('button').click(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome when the dialog shows, scrollbars appear as something is exceeding the window boundaries.  Also, when you move the scrollbars, they are locked.  In IE9, the browser crashes.  This code seems simple enough.

I have also created a jsFiddle example...
http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/RcR8e/

Can someone tell what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the jquery ui css file.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/RcR8e/7/

There are several to choose from on the [jquery ui site under themes](http://jqueryui.com/download). The fiddle uses http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css